# and operation overloading in python

Tags: python

I know logically `and` is used for booleans evaluating to true if both the conditions are true, but I have a problem with the following statement:

```
print "ashish" and "sahil"

it prints out "sahil"?
 another example:
 return s[0] == s[-1] and checker(s[1:-1])
 (taken from recursive function for palindrome string
 checking            
please explain it and other ways and is oveloaded ,especially what the second statement do.
```

Comment: what do you want it to print?

Comment: Python's logical operators don't return booleans. Take a look at the documentation: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Answer (score 10):

`and` is not overloaded.

In your code, `"ashish"` is a truthy value  (because non-empty strings are truthy), so it evaluates `"sahil"`.  As `"sahil"` is also a truthy value, `"sahil"` is returned to the print statement and is then printed.

Comment: Even if "sahil" weren't truthy, it would still be the value returned by the `and` operator.

Comment: @MattBryant: As @chepner said, the second element is returned always, unless the first element is considered false (eg. empty string, `False`, zero, empty list etc.).

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have explained that, but I figure @chepner covered it fine.

Answer (score 7):

`x and y` basically means:

> return `y`, unless `x` is False-ish - in such case return `x`

Here is a list of possible combinations:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> items = [True, False, 0, 1, 2, '', 'yes', 'no']
>>> for a, b in combinations(items, 2):
    print '%r and %r => %r' % (a, b, a and b)


True and False => False
True and 0 => 0
True and 1 => 1
True and 2 => 2
True and '' => ''
True and 'yes' => 'yes'
True and 'no' => 'no'
False and 0 => False
False and 1 => False
False and 2 => False
False and '' => False
False and 'yes' => False
False and 'no' => False
0 and 1 => 0
0 and 2 => 0
0 and '' => 0
0 and 'yes' => 0
0 and 'no' => 0
1 and 2 => 2
1 and '' => ''
1 and 'yes' => 'yes'
1 and 'no' => 'no'
2 and '' => ''
2 and 'yes' => 'yes'
2 and 'no' => 'no'
'' and 'yes' => ''
'' and 'no' => ''
'yes' and 'no' => 'no'
```

Comment: For a moment I thought you manually typed all those operations(then I scrolled up and found `combinations`). ;-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I would not dare ;) I could however just paste the output, so I would not need to explain what `combinations` does, but this way I gave OP not only the answer, but also tool to explore it further.

Answer (score 4):

If the result of the expression to the left of `and` is falsy, it evaluates to that. Otherwise, it evaluates to the result of the expression on its right. `"ashish"` is truthy.